# Aggregation $filter is not working after $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to filter data after the lookup operator. I am not getting the expected behaviour out of my query.

My gateway collection is

```
{ "_id" : "18001887", "mac_id" : "18001887", group_id: "0" }
{ "_id" : "18001888", "mac_id" : "18001888", group_id: "1" }
{ "_id" : "18001889", "mac_id" : "18001889", group_id: "0" }
```

My commands collection is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("615581dcb9ebca6c37eb39e4"),
    "org_id" : 0,
    "mac_id" : "18001887",
    "config" : {
        "user_info" : [ 
            {
                "user_id" : 1,
                "user_pwd" : "123456",
                "mapped_id" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "user_id" : 2,
                "user_pwd" : "123123",
                "mapped_id" : 3
            }
        ]
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("615581dcb9ebca6c37eb39e4"),
    "org_id" : 0,
    "mac_id" : "18001889",
    "config" : {
        "slave_id" : 1 
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the commands of gateways with group_id = 0 and "config.user_info.mapped_id" = 1.
I wrote the below query but it doesn't seem to work

```
gateway_model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    group_id: "0"
                },
                
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    mac_id: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "commands",
                    localField: "mac_id",
                    foreignField: "mac_id",
                    as: "childs"
                    
                }
            },
            { 
                $project: {
                    mac_id: 1,
                    childs: {
                        $filter: {
                            "input": "$childs",
                            "as": "child",
                            "cond": {"$eq": ["$$child.config.user_info.mapped_id", 1]},
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

Above query returns gateways with group_id 0 and childs is an empty array.

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work.  The `$filter` operator will return an array containing any elements that match the `cond`.  If there are no matches, the array will be empty.

Comment: But in this case there is a `child.config.user_info.mapped_id = 1`. Check the command collection example. I am using the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `user_info` is array and you are checking equal-to condition in `$filter` operation, You can change your `$filter` condition as per below,

- When we access `mapped_id` from array field `$$child.config.user_info.mapped_id`, it will return array of ids so we need to use `$in` condition
- `$ifNull` to check if `user_info` field is not present then it will return blank array
- `$in` operator to check is 1 in `mapped_id`'s array

```
  {
    $project: {
      mac_id: 1,
      childs: {
        $filter: {
          "input": "$childs",
          "as": "child",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              1,
              { $ifNull: ["$$child.config.user_info.mapped_id", []] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oytj7DFKqHJ)

---

The second option and this is right way to handle this situation, `$lookup` using pipeline,

- `let` to pass `mac_id` to pipeline
- check `$expr` condition for `mac_id`
- match `mapped_id` condition

```
db.gateway.aggregate([
  { $match: { group_id: "0" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "commands",
      let: { mac_id: "$mac_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$mac_id", "$$mac_id"] },
            "config.user_info.mapped_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "childs"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      mac_id: 1,
      childs: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nsraSwrpUrL)

If you want to filter `user_info` array then you can add one more stage after `$match` stage in `$lookup` stage,

```
{
  $addFields: {
    "config.user_info": {
      $filter: {
        input: "$config.user_info",
        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.mapped_id", 1] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fp_eo9wDS0q)